# Sudo user don't have access to transfering data via SFTP

Tags: permissions, sudo, ftp, sftp, filezilla

I have small VPS server. I create new user and add him privileges via sudo visudo like root. I can do anything via console, but i can't transfer any data via filezilla ( SFTP ) beacuse im receiving alert permission denied...

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Please understand how sudo works. Sudo allows a user to run the command sudo, to run something as root. The user is **NOT** root, so any actions done without sudo **has the permissions of the user**. So this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Im know that, dont worry, but how i can transfer data via SFTP without root access? Can i give privileges to allow modify all data via SFTP to user?

Comment: Yes, you can add a second user with UID 0, or you can ssh to the root user.  But I do struggle to see *any* sane reason for wanting this...

Comment: So login to SFTP via root is safe? Because a lot of tutorials said "disable root login" or "do not operating server via root account". ;p

Comment: As long as you use key based authentication it's secure enough. It's not any less secure than allowing another user to do what ever root can do.